# Using Braintree DropIn with Jetpack compose?

Tags: kotlin, braintree

What dependency of **DropIn** should I use?

Version 6.9 doesn't have `DropInRequest().clientToken()` and version 3.0 has it, but just adding that dependency makes my project not compile. So I either need to know where to add the `clientToken` in Version 6.9 or do I need to make my project compile with Version 3.0?

Thanks in advance